# how to show url of site with image and detalies in android

Tags: android, url, textview

I want to put **URL** in textview and make it show just like in facebook or instagram [image]
without opening the site.
exactly like this example.

how i can do that any help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open string(url) in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279709/how-to-open-stringurl-in-webview)

Comment: no i need when put a  url in textview show the site details without open the site like facebook in recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what exactly what i want **Web Preview**  in github [here](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview)